# HIVE partition & bucketing support in Spark not working as expected

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

When working with partitions in S3, Spark is listing down all the partitions one by one, which is consuming time.Rather it should look for the partition in the meta-store table & should go to the partition immediately.
I tried with an example of 125 partitions.When I calculate the exact location of the S3 by appending the partition column value & try to access it, it executes within 5sec.But if I try to let Spark figures out the partition, it is listing down all the partitions, which itself is taking more than 30 sec.
How can I let Spark figures out the partition from the meta-store using the predicate push-down?

Comment: Are you using EMR for this?

Comment: can you add the code you tried? So that it would easy for others to understand/reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes. I am using EMR.
    peopleDF
      .write
      .partitionBy("city")
      .bucketBy(42, "age")
      .saveAsTable("people_partitioned_bucketed")

Comment: @mrsrinivas: I am using following code snippet.
            peopleDF
      .write
      .partitionBy("city")
      .bucketBy(42, "age")
      .saveAsTable("people_partitioned_bucketed")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup external hive metastore(it can be mysql or postgres). So the definitions of tables/partitions will be persisted there and will survive different spark context lifespans

Comment: Isn't it if I am using HiveContext in Spark, it should use the derby database by default to store the meta-store information?

Comment: depends. How do you submit your spark jobs? just one reason it won't work : if you using yarn-cluster mode your driver will find itself everytime on different node. Derby is not meant to be used in production.

Comment: Can you please suggest any method where spark will pick the exact partition if i have stored the data in multiple partition using predicate pushdown and how to support bucket.Now it seems the partition information only lies within a sparksession.

Comment: I've already suggested that you can use external hive metastore, why it's not good for you?